# How to cross-compile ffplay for Android on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, android, sdl

I'm trying to obtain an ffplay binary to use it in my Android app. But when I run my configure script, it says that sdl2 in not found although I cross-compiled it too and put its headers and library flags to --extra-cflags and --extraldflags. If I remove --enable-sdl2 ffplay simply wont appear in the list of the programs to be built.
I managed to get it to compile on release/3.2 branch, but it throws an error regarding an undefined reference to 'main' in ether ffplay or libavutil.so files (depending on shared and/or static flags).
Then I edited sdl2_cflags and sdl2_extralibs variables in the configure file on the master branch to point to my library, but it won't compile anyway.
What am I doing wrong?

My configure file has been changed this way:

```
if enabled sdl2; then
    sdl2_cflags="-I/home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/include -D_REENTRANT"
    sdl2_extralibs="-L/home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/build/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a -lSDL2"
    enable sdl2
fi
```

And here's my script:

```
make_or_die() {
    make -j $(nproc) || exit
    sudo make install || exit
}

ARCH=arm
API=17
CPU=armv7

WORKING_DIR=~/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg

NDK=~/Android/SDK/ndk
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 

FFMPEG_PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 

SDL=$(pwd)/sdl2
SDL_PREFIX=$SDL/build/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a

export PATH=$PATH:$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$TOOLCHAIN/include
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-clang"
export CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-clang++"

build_sdl2() {
    hg clone https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL $SDL
    cd $SDL
    sudo ./build-scripts/androidbuildlibs.sh
    cd $WORKING_DIR
    echo "SDL build folder: $SDL_PREFIX"
}

build_ffmpeg() {
    sudo make distclean
    sudo ./configure \
        --target-os=android \
        --arch=$ARCH \
        --prefix=$FFMPEG_PREFIX \
        --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-ffprobe \
        --disable-ffmpeg \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-symver \
        && make_or_die && header "Success! Your files are at $FFMPEG_PREFIX" \
        || (echo \\n && tail ffbuild/config.log && exit)
}

build_sdl2
build_ffmpeg
```

**UPD:** I've managed to get an executable my putting these lines in the configure file, but neither ffmpeg not ffplay built this way are working. Their processes exit with code 132 which is related to a corrupt binary AFAIK. I still don't know how to get them working.

```
sdl2_cflags="-I/home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/include -D_REENTRANT"
sdl2_extralibs="/home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/build/android/lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so /home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/build/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.a /home/kondenko/Android/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/sdl2/build/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2main.a -llog -landroid -ldl -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -shared"
enable sdl2
```